# create contact automatically from a custom object

Tags: process-builder

we use a custom object called 'Application' When a picklist value on 'Application' record change to 'accepted' a new 'contact' needs to be created and the Application record needs to be attached to this newly created 'contact'. I'm able to create a new 'contact' with the help of process builder but I'm not able to link/attach the 'application' record to it. I've created a lookup relationship from 'Application' to 'Contact' but unable to figure out how to link them in process builder.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what you've done so far and specifically where you are stuck in this objective. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is achievable if you follow the below link:
 https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000l9TTQAY

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read [answer]. We look for posts to contain complete answers to the question, and link to outside sources as support, not primary content.